# WSO2 OAuth2 Playground Introspection Endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying this [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/OAuth+2.0+with+WSO2+Playground).

What should I put in the `Introspection Endpoint`? this is the phase when I have the `Access Token` and I need to request the resource

Or how to find the configuration of the introspection endpoint and why is it even asking for that endpoint?

Comment: At where does that exactly mention about `Introspection Endpoint`? I couldn't find it in the doc you're pointing at.

Comment: it's not in the docs that's why im a little confuse why it is showing. But if you refer to the docs, it is [here](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/js1hdW05x8BXskbwkX0IATN-5MlpXdt8hkHluifjDg5XRoGiXqPjU1IvnrCBh1htXWwfM3F_tnwXka00UhQFxqIcONbK8ibQxB2uWKlf2D3fkpAHUgK30q0NqwNuVt-jw48HUHbZ), i got an additional field "Introspecion endpoint"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using master branch of `product-is` git repo. If you're using IS 5.2.0, you should use that branch. 5.2.0 branch should not have such an endpoint. As mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Downloading+a+Sample), change the branch to v5.2.0 after you clone samples in the git repo.

```
git checkout -b v5.2.0 v5.2.0
```

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Downloading+a+Sample

Comment: right! i missed that. To verify, v5.2.0 is meant for that tutorial and master for production?

Comment: No. v5.2.0 is for IS-5.2.0 release, and master is for next version of IS which will be IS-5.3.0.